# MDI form in monodevelop gtk-sharp

Tags: gtk, monodevelop, mdiparent

Want to create MDIform applucation in monodevelop gtk-sharp, but not able to find MDI Parent child form options.

Requesting help

Comment: Show us what you already done, so we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDI (Multiple Document Interface) is not something that GTK# supports natively. The design principle behind GTK# is to abstract the window management away to the windowing engine and the configuration the user has specified on their OS. MDI tends to be Windows-centric, there are parallels in other OS but not generally exactly the same. My advice having been down this path before is to avoid MDI and design your application to be agnostic of the windowing engine.